# Case-insensitive auto-completion for QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have this simple program:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QLineEdit>

QStringList slNames={
    "anna",
    "andrew",
    "ashley",
    "brian",
    "brianna",
    "brandon",
    "cameron",
    "daniel",
    "danna",
    "devon",
    "derek",
    "emma"
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    QApplication appMain(argc,argv);
    QComboBox    cboNames;
    cboNames.setEditable(true);
    QObject::disconnect(
        cboNames.lineEdit(),
        &QLineEdit::editingFinished,
        nullptr,
        nullptr
    ); // Added (2023-01-25)
    QObject::connect(
        cboNames.lineEdit(),
        &QLineEdit::textEdited,
        [&](const QString &sText) {
            //cboNames.lineEdit()->blockSignals(true); Removed (2023-01-25)
            cboNames.clear();
            cboNames.hidePopup();
            if(sText.length()) {
                for(const auto &n:slNames)
                    if(n.startsWith(sText,Qt::CaseInsensitive))
                        cboNames.addItem(n);
                cboNames.showPopup();
                cboNames.setEditText(sText);
                cboNames.lineEdit()->grabKeyboard();
            }
            //cboNames.lineEdit()->blockSignals(false); Removed (2023-01-25)
        }
    );
    cboNames.show();
    return appMain.exec();
}
```

So, typing "d", for example, shows you 4 results, with autocompletion, etc.
But if you type "D" instead, the results are shown, but the autocompletion does not work anymore and just picks the full first result.

I know this has to do with QCompleter but I've not been able to make it work.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT** (2023-01-25):

After struggling with QCompleter (*works marvels for a standalone QLineEdit but could not find a way of making it work flawlessly for the QComboBox*), I noticed that something was firing *textEdited*/*textChanged*, no matter the use of blockSignals().

So I used `cboNames.lineEdit()->disconnect();` and that worked, but ultimately found that *editingFinished* was the culprit.

I've not found any disadvantages of this. It's a weird thing to do but it does the job in less lines of code.

Consider that this program is just a MRE. The actual list contents are dynamic.